# Android: How to transfer video and audio via bluetooth connection?

Tags: java, android, audio, video, bluetooth

I want to transfer a live video stream and audio to my computer. Something like the WO Webcam app (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bwocamlite). I have managed to connect my device with the computer, now how do I transfer the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to transfer audio and video over Bluetooth is using standard profiles A2DP and VDP respectively.
Standard android versions does not support VDP for video , also the PC side needs to have these profiles sink roles in order to receive the streams.

The WO Webcam app uses the SPP profile to send video frames and audio packets over Bluetooth and it re-constructs the same on the PC and plays back, you can also do the same.

Comment: great! thanks.. so Im guessing this tutorial here would work right? http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client/ Can you also please explain the difference between the two above said methods. Are there any disadvantages of using the SPP method?

Comment: Android has a good sample application that uses SPP - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html The advantage of using standard methods are that if the devices support the profiles the it is interoperable, also use of codecs like SBC for audio and H.263 for video will get some compression, in addiiton links gets pre-negotiated for a certian bandwidth requriements that radios ties to reserve / keep for the streaming. With SPP you basically transfer the raw bytes and you have to do the compression and buffering etc to achieve the requried streaming quality

Comment: @DennisMathews [plz look into the link and help me out!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291776/route-audio-song-to-blue-tooth-programmatically) ..... Thanks