# Route Audio song to blue-tooth programmatically?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

How to listen my audio file from Blue-Tooth device, programmatically? 
I have already route my audio file in between front and rear speaker, while routing over Bluetooth.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228442/android-how-to-transfer-video-and-audio-via-bluetooth-connection?lq=1

Comment: It would help to have more information--is the audio file playing on an Anrdoid device and you want to stream to something else, playing on something else and you want to stream to your Android device, or something else altogether?

Comment: @Talha Hafeez: did you resolve this thing, as I want to implement similar thing in my project?

Answer (score 0):

If the device is connected to a bluetooth, audio played through the device will be streamed through bluetooth only right?

So maybe you can first check whether the device is connected to a bluetooth device with :

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
if(audioManager.isBluetoothA2dpOn()) {
    // Play audio...
}
```

Android's [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) class has more details what you can dig into.

If the bluetooth is not connected you can programmatically check and connect to available bluetooth devices using Androids bluetooth [package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html).